# Create a random BigInt for Miller-Rabin test

Tags: javascript, random, primes

I'm implementing a [Miller Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) using JavaScript BigInts.

The basic algorithm is no problem - I have that done, but it requires a random number in the range 0 to (number being tested-3). I can't use `Math.random()` and scale since I'm using BigInt.

This doesn't need to be cryptographically secure, just random enough, so I've opted for generating a string of randomly selected hex digits and converting that to a BigInt.

Here's the code:

```
function getRandomBigint(lower, upper) {

    // Convert to hex strings so that we know how many digits to generate
    let hexDigits = new Array(upper.toString(16).length).fill('');
    let rand;
    let newDigits;
    do {
        // Fill the array with random hex digits and convert to a BigInt
        newDigits = hexDigits.map(()=>Math.floor(Math.random()*16).toString(16));
        rand = BigInt('0x'+newDigits.join(''));
    } while (rand < lower || rand > upper);
    return rand;
}
```

The problem here is that the generated number could be out of range. This function handles that (badly) by iterating until it gets a number in range. Obviously, that could potentially take a very long time. In practice it has never iterated more than a couple of dozen times before delivering a number, but the nature of randomness means that the problem is 'out there' waiting to bite me!

I could scale or truncate the result to get it in range, rather than iterating, but I am concerned that this would affect the randomness. I already have some evidence that this is not as random as it might be, but that might not matter in this application.

So, two questions:

- is this random enough for Miller Rabin?
- how to deal with results out of range?

This is a JavaScript-only project - no libraries, please.

Comment: You could use `crypto.getRandomValues` to fill a Uint8Array of the appropriate length with random bytes (actually cryptographically secure, even if you don't care here) and then tweak only the last byte, or use `Math.random` for it, to get the exact range required. Then convert the byte array to a BigInt (sadly not a very efficient operation for now, but probably doesn't matter).

Comment: @Touffy `crypto.getRandomValues` might improve the randomness of the value I initially obtain, but it's the tweaking of the last byte that gives trouble. If the highest order hex digit of my original number is 1 then almost every random value I obtain for that digit will need tweaking. My first attempt (just to discard that digit) skewed the results heavily to the low end of the value range. I have another idea that I'm testing which might simplify the whole problem.

Comment: Oh, no, getRandomValues would just be a more concise way of filling an array with random values than a loop with Math.random like you're doing. As for the last byte, my idea was to multiply Math.random with the maximum value of your range + 1 so you always end up within your range, without skewing.

Answer (score 0):

The Miller Rabin test is a probabilistic<sup>1</sup> test. That is, it is deterministic for establishing that a number is **not** prime, but a prime indication is only that - an indication that a number **might** be prime.

The reason is that certain bases used in the test can result in a prime indication, even when the target number is not prime. The use of a random number as a base in the test allows for the test to be run repeatedly with a different base each time, thus increasing the probability that the result correctly indicates prime or not prime<sup>2</sup>.

Thus, the random numbers selected must just be less than the number being tested. There is no requirement for them to be selected from the complete range.

With this in mind I now have this:

```
function getRandomBigInt(upper) {
    let maxInt = BigInt(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
    if (upper <= maxInt) {
        return BigInt((Math.floor(Math.random()*Number(upper))));
    } else {
        return BigInt((Math.floor(Math.random()*Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)));
    }

}
```

9007199254740991 (`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`) should provide a sufficiently large range of numbers for this purpose. It works with my Miller-Rabin implementation as far as I have tested it so far.

<sup>1</sup> Testing numbers up to 3,317,044,064,679,887,385,961,981 against a short specific list of bases will yield a definitive prime/not prime result.

<sup>2</sup> For non-deterministic prime results it is still necessary to perform a deterministic test (such as trial division) to confirm.

Answer (score -2):

A way to get random number in a range is

```
  lower + rand() % (upper - lower)
```

rand() is any function that returns a random number larger than (upper - lower).  The math can be done with Integer or Bigint.

```
function rand16() {
    // 0 .. 2^16-1
    return BigInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*65536));
}
function rand() {
   // -2^63 .. 2^63-1
   return BigInt( (((rand16() * 65536) + rand16())* 65536 + rand16()) * 65536 + rand16() );
}
```

Comment: what is `rand()` ?

Comment: We are asking exactly how to write the function `rand`